# Meteor/Angular2 Application freeze when loading 2nd Component

Tags: angular, typescript, meteor, angular-meteor, angular2-meteor

I got a Problem with my Meteor/Angular2 application. I got a start Component (AppComponent) and I can load this just fine everything works as I want. But now **I added the tag 'map' to my AppComponent template and created the component MapComponent**. Now everytime i try to open the application (on localhost:3000) the **App freezes and crashes**. I can't open the developer tool nothing.

Here i send you my Files:
app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { MapComponent } from './map/map.component';

@NgModule({
  // Components, Pipes, Directive
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MapComponent

  ],
  // Providers
  providers: [],
  // Modules
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  // Main Component
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import template from "./app.component.html";
import style from "./app.component.scss";

@Component({
  selector: "app",
  template: `<nav class="navbar">Navbar</nav>
<div class="mapbox">
    <map></map>
</div>
<footer class="footer">Footer</footer>`,
  styles: [ style ]
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

map.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'map',
    template: `<div class="container">
    Test
</div>`,
    styleUrls: ['../app.component.scss']
})
export class MapComponent {

}
```

I hope you can help me.
Thanks in advance
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `styleUrls` from Angular (instead of `import style from './path/to/stylesheet'` from angular2-meteor), remember that:

> The URL is relative to the *application root*, which is usually the location of the `index.html` web page that hosts the application. The style file URL is *not* relative to the component file.

Reference: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#style-urls-in-metadata

Therefore in your case, you would write in your `map.component.ts` file:

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'map',
    template: `<div class="container">
    Test
</div>`,
    styleUrls: ['app/app.component.scss'] // From location of index.html
})
export class MapComponent {}
```

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/K0NW0g8UVRI1EsyRMIe6?p=preview

---

There is however a way to request Angular to [use relative path](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#relative-urls).

> You can use a relative URL by prefixing your filenames with `./`:

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'map',
    template: `<div class="container">
    Test
</div>`,
    styleUrls: ['./../app.component.scss'] // From location of map.component.ts
})
export class MapComponent {}
```

Demo2: https://plnkr.co/edit/5x0qFBii2VIQOCtpxLfL?p=preview

Note: you must start with `./`, not directly `../`, otherwise Angular still uses absolute path URL.

---

That being said, if you use that code within Meteor, all your files will be bundled during compilation, and you cannot use the Angular way of lazily loading external files (whether HTML or stylesheets).

Therefore you should either write those inline, or use the `angular2-meteor` importing recommended way, i.e.:

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import style from '../app.component.scss';
@Component({
    selector: 'map',
    template: `<div class="container">
    Test
</div>`,
    styles: [style]
})
export class MapComponent {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The advices are great inputs for the future. Unfortuantly this isn't the Solution for my Problem. I think the Problem is more on the side of Meteor.

Comment: Yep thinking about it actually, there is a very high chance your SCSS file is no longer accessible at the expected URL once Meteor bundles everything. That is why you should simply stick with `angular2-meteor` import style, i.e. `import style from '../app.component.scss.'` then `styles: [style]` in the `@Component` decorator.

Comment: Thanks! The last part of your solution solved my Problem. You are my man:)